# Sphinx Autodoc vs. Coverage: Am I missing something here?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm trying to use Sphinx to document a Python package which contains various sub-packages and sub-modules. I followed the stock Sphinx quickstart script which produced various files with `autodoc` directives that, in turn, with the `html` generator, produced a mostly-as-expected first-pass of the docs based on existing docstrings in the code. Cool.

Now enter `sphinx.ext.coverage`. With the project existing as it does after the "quickstart" script, running `sphinx-build -b coverage <other args>` doesn't produce any meaningful output at all, just:

```
Undocumented Python objects
===========================
```

...with nothing at all below it. I deliberately remove some docstrings to make sure, and sure enough, no warnings.

I thrashed around for a while and eventually tried using the non-`autodoc` directives, and lo and behold, `coverage` suddenly appears to work. Sadly, the `autodoc` functionality is a large part of what makes Sphinx appealing in the first place. But OK, putting in a `.. py:module::` directive for each of the modules helps; it appears to make the `coverage` extension aware of my modules, and from there I start to get entries in my `python.txt` about members within those modules that don't have docstrings. That's great, but it appears to mean that for `coverage` to report on a module, that module has to be explicitly, manually declared in the doc files, which kinda reduces the value of a `coverage` tool (i.e. if I add a new module to the package, it appears it won't be included in the coverage report until I specifically add a directive for it.) So, what I'm seeing is that `autodoc` seems capable of automatically traversing sub-modules/packages, but `coverage` does not.

**Question**: Am I missing something? The inability to automatically discover new code appearing in a project seems like a pretty **glaring fault** for a "coverage" tool. It seems to me like a standard coverage tool ought to be opt-out, not opt-in.

As I pushed further, I found even yet more evidence that `coverage` and `autodoc` aren't friends. For instance, even when declaring modules manually with `.. py:module::` directives (as described above), I find that `coverage` is not picking up on things like `autodoc`'s `exclude-members` directive. This directive, as expected, elides matching members from the generated output when building HTML, but `coverage` still reports those members as undocumented in its coverage report. From my reading

**Question**: Is this incompatibility between `coverage` and `autodoc` noted somewhere in the docs that I've not been able to find? Or, again, am I missing something?

Comment: I'm greatly interested in an answer to this question as well. I'm experiencing the same issues and I'm finding it quite aggravating.